# Prove identity of partial derivatives

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I can not do the following problem:

Prove the identity:

$$\left( \frac{\partial x}{\partial y} \right)_{z}\left( \frac{\partial y}{\partial z} \right)_{x}\left( \frac{\partial z}{\partial x} \right)_{y}=-1$$

State the properties that must be $x=x(y,z)$, $y=y(x,z)$, $z=(x,y)$.

The truth is I do not know how to start, and they do not know how to interpret the functions $x$, $y$, $z$. Any help or explanation will be the most grateful.